# Using UsageStatsManager to monitor time spent on Android app

Tags: android, usagestatsmanager

I am trying to implement an Android app that could notify the user when they have spent X amount of time on a social media app like Facebook or Instagram. I am aware that queryUsageStats() from UsageStatsManager is [the preferred way to go](http://blog.tunebrains.com/2015/10/20/usage-stats-manager-sample.html) but according to the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html) intervals only span for less than a day. Is it at all possible to query once every hour or two so that I could send out notifications in a timely manner?

Answer (score 0):

I was recently trying to get same information using UsageStats and UsageStatsManager class, but looks like these classes are not meant for that purpose.

To answer your question, yes it is possible to query for an hour or two by passing parameters to class `queryUsageStats(int intervalType, long beginTime, long endTime)`, but unfortunately while getting results `List<UsageStats>`, will not be be limited for the specific period, returned data may be more than for the period you passed as a parameter.

UsageStats and UsageStatsManager are more useful to get aggregate data like how much a specific app is using in a day or week or month or year, and when it was used last time, and when it was used last time